# Load Lottie JSON file dynamically in React

Tags: reactjs, lottie

How do you load the JSON files dynamically for Lottie in ReactJS? If I want to design a dynamic menu and I want the icon (Lottie) to change based on the file name passed to it. Is this possible? And how to also change the color of a Lottie file?

I was unable to find this information anymore. Can anymore help?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try dynamically but you can try this.

```
import { useLottie } from "lottie-react";
const options = {
    animationData: animationData, // you can set dynamic data
    loop: true,
  };
const { View } = useLottie(options); // you can also try this {animationData:your data,loop:true}

<>{View}</> // lottie will show
```

let me know if its works for you or not. note: it works for a single lottie files.